# SSMS won't connect to SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have Microsoft SQL Server manager version 18.8 installed to my PC, as well as SQL Server 2019. Both are installed on my PC. I need to locally create and manage a database.

[image: [1]]

I am trying to connect the SSMS but it's not working.
[image: [2]]

I entered to the services and restarted everything
[image: [3]]

and I also enabled TCP/IP in configuration manager.
[image: [4]]

what should I do?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: If you're accessing from the same PC you should enable Named Pipes, better perf than TCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have a **named instance** of SQL Server named `SQLEXPRESS` (this is shown in parentheses within the SQL Server service name "`SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)`" in the Windows Services MMC snap-in.
- You need to specify the instance-name in the `Server name:` field.
- You can only omit the instance-name for **default instances**.

You need to specify `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` to be able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting using `.\SQLEXPRESS` as the server name.

It seems you have created an instance with the name `SQLEXPRESS`. With SQL server you can create "instances". Each instance is like its own separate database engine and has its own list of databases, users and so forth. There can be one **default instance** which would be just the computer name or `.`. In your case you have a **named instance** "SQLEXPRESS" which you need to address using `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `<computername>\SQLEXPRESS`.